# graphite server echo command working but no data from tcl

Tags: php, mysql, tcl, echo, graphite

Tclsh is used to echo data to local graphite server.

```
set graphite1_ip 127.0.0.1
set graphite1_port 2003
set snmp_RSSI [exec snmpwalk -Os -c public -v 2c 192.168.1.20 .1.3.6.1.4.1.31926.2.1.1.19]
set splitted_RSSI [regexp -inline -all -- {\S+} $snmp_RSSI]
set radio_RSSI [lindex $splitted_RSSI 3]
puts $radio_RSSI
puts $graphite1_ip
puts $graphite1_port
exec echo "radio.RSSI $radio_RSSI" | nc $graphite1_ip $graphite1_port
```

The result is:

```
-56
127.0.0.1
2003
```

However, I could not see any data uploaded to graphite server nor any folder being created...so there must be something wrong with this code, when I do:

```
puts $radio_RSSI
```

the "$radio_RSSI" color is green, and in:

```
exec echo "radio.RSSI $radio_RSSI" | nc $graphite1_ip $graphite1_port
```

the "radio.RSSI $radio_RSSI" color is pink, which means the $radio_RSSI is not recognized as a value(-56)

Comment: Is a negative value something you expect to use for the `radio_RSSI` parameter? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: You don't need the `echo` call: use [`exec`](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/exec.htm) to redirect nc's stdin: `exec nc $graphite1_ip $graphite1_port << "radio.RSSI $radio_RSSI"`

Comment: Hi Donal yes I am trying to upload -56 to the server. I did not get any error message, but I just could not see any data upload to the server; and yes you are right, all data I uploaded to the server is positive so far...

Comment: Hi glenn jackman, thanks for your recommendation. I just tried it, no error massage, but I still did not see any data uploading...

Answer (score 0):

The line you're sending to graphite only includes the metric name and the metric value.  There is no time-stamp.  I just did a quick testing against my server:

```
echo "test.dummydata 4 `date +%s`" | nc -q0 127.0.0.1 2023
echo "test.dummydata2 4" | nc -q0 127.0.0.1 2023
```

Reviewing `/opt/graphite/storage/log/carbon-cache/carbon-cache-a/creates.log`, I could see that `test/dummydata.wsp` was created, but not `test/dummydata2.wsp`.

So it looks like your data is being dropped because of the missing time-stamp.